# Model and Computed Property interaction in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using vue.js I am trying to build a simple task manager.

When a user clicks the "complete" checkbox I want two things to happen:

1. If the "Show all tasks" is unchecked, hide the task.
2. Send an ajax request to the server to mark the task as complete/open.

The impotent parts are shown below:

```
<div id="tasks-app">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="show_all">
<label for="checkbox">Show all tasks</label><br>

<table class="table">
  <tr><th v-for="column in table_columns" v-text="column"></th><tr>
  <tr v-for="row in visibleTasks" :class="{danger: !row.daily_task.complete && row.daily_task.delayed, success: row.daily_task.complete}">
    <td v-text="row.task.name"></td>
    <td v-text="row.task.deadline"></td>
    <td v-text="row.daily_task.status"></td>
    <td v-text="row.daily_task.task_user"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="updateStatus(row)" v-model="row.daily_task.complete" >Complete</input>
    </td>
    <td><input v-model="row.daily_task.delay_reason"></input></td>
</table>
</div>
```

And the VUE.js code:

```
app = new Vue({
  el: '#tasks-app',

  data: {
    table_columns: ['Task','Deadline','Status','User','Actions','Reason'],
    tasks: [],
    filter_string: '',
    show_all: false
  },

  computed: {
    visibleTasks() {

      show_all = this.show_all

      if(show_all){
         search_filter = this.tasks         
      }else{
         search_filter = _.filter(this.tasks,function(task){
            return !task.daily_task.complete;
         })
      }
      return search_filter
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateStatus(row){
      var id = row.daily_task.id
      var complete = row.daily_task.complete
      if(complete){
        axios.get('set_task_complete/' + id)
      }else{
        axios.get('set_task_open/' + id)
      }
    }

  }

})
```

If the show all checkbox is checked, this works as expected. The data changes and then the `updateStatus` function is called.

If however the show all checkbox is unchecked, the visibleTasks will trigger and the logic for the `updateStatus` will fail, as the row will be hidden and the ID that is send to the server will be off by one. If the row hides before `updateStatus`is called the wrong row is passed to the `updateStatus` function.

I could solve this by adding a filter update at the end of `updateStatus` function but that does not seems to utilize the Vue.js library. Could someone help me what components of Vue you would use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a lot if you separate the logic:

1. Loop over every tasks (completed or not) to display them (without considering `show_all`)
2. Update tasks with `v-on:click="updateStatus(row)"`
3. On each `tr`, add `v-show="show_all || !row.status.complete"`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is use both change event handle and model. Both actually, trigger at same time when you click on the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="updateStatus(row)" v-model="row.daily_task.complete" >Complete</input>
```

You should edit your code use only `v-on:change="updateStatus(row)"`. After updateStatus complete ajax calls toggle `row.daily_task.complete` to trigger  `visibleTasks` to update your view.

```
updateStatus(row){
      var id = row.daily_task.id
      var complete = !row.daily_task.complete
      var p;
      if(complete){
        p = axios.get('set_task_complete/' + id)
      }else{
        p = axios.get('set_task_open/' + id)
      }
      p.then(() => row.daily_task.complete = complete)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code a bit and it seems to work fine:

1. you shouldn't use `v-on:change`, instead, use `<input type="checkbox" v-on:click="updateStatus(row)" v-bind:checked="row.daily_task.complete">`
2. Don't update `row.daily_task.complete` straight away, update it only when the asynchronous axios is complete.

```js
const fakeUpdateComplete = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(true); });
};

const fakeUpdateIncomplete = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(true); });
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#tasks-app',

  data: {
    history: [],
    table_columns: ['Task','Deadline','Status','User','Actions','Reason'],
    tasks: [
      {
        task: {
          name: 'A',
          deadline: '2017-01-01',
        },
        daily_task: {
          id: 1,
          status: '',
          task_user: '',
          complete: true,
          delayed: false,
          delay_reason: ''
        }
      },
      {
        task: {
          name: 'B',
          deadline: '2017-01-02',
        },
        daily_task: {
          id: 2,
          status: '',
          task_user: '',
          complete: false,
          delayed: false,
          delay_reason: ''
        }
      },
      {
        task: {
          name: 'C',
          deadline: '2017-01-03',
        },
        daily_task: {
          id: 3,
          status: '',
          task_user: '',
          complete: false,
          delayed: false,
          delay_reason: ''
        }
      },
      {
        task: {
          name: 'D',
          deadline: '2017-01-03',
        },
        daily_task: {
          id: 4,
          status: '',
          task_user: '',
          complete: true,
          delayed: false,
          delay_reason: ''
        }
      },
      {
        task: {
          name: 'E',
          deadline: '2017-01-03',
        },
        daily_task: {
          id: 5,
          status: '',
          task_user: '',
          complete: false,
          delayed: false,
          delay_reason: ''
        }
      }
    ],
    filter_string: '',
    show_all: true
  },

  computed: {
    visibleTasks() {
      const show_all = this.show_all
      let search_filter;
      if(show_all){
         search_filter = this.tasks         
      }else{
        console.log(this.tasks);
        search_filter = this.tasks.filter(task => {
          return !task.daily_task.complete
        });
      }
      return search_filter
    }
  },

  methods: {
    updateStatus(row){
      const id = row.daily_task.id;
      const complete = !row.daily_task.complete;
       
      if (complete) {
        
        fakeUpdateComplete(id).then(() => {
           this.history.push(`Task ${row.task.name} with id ${row.daily_task.id} is marked as complete`);
           row.daily_task.complete = !row.daily_task.complete;
        });
      } else {
        fakeUpdateIncomplete(id).then(() => {
           this.history.push(`Task ${row.task.name} with id ${row.daily_task.id} is marked as incomplete`);
           row.daily_task.complete = !row.daily_task.complete;
        });
      }
      /*
      if(complete){
        axios.get('set_task_complete/' + id)
      }else{
        axios.get('set_task_open/' + id)
      }
      */
    }

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="tasks-app">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="show_all">
<label for="checkbox">Show all tasks</label><br>

<table class="table">
  <tr><th v-for="column in table_columns" v-text="column"></th><tr>
  <tr 
    v-for="row in visibleTasks" 
    :class="{danger: !row.daily_task.complete && row.daily_task.delayed, success: row.daily_task.complete}"
  >
    <td>{{row.task.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.task.deadline}}</td>
    <td>{{row.daily_task.status}}</td>
    <td>{{row.daily_task.task_user}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="updateStatus(row)" v-bind:checked="row.daily_task.complete">
      <label for="complete">Complete</label>
    </td>
    <td><input v-model="row.daily_task.delay_reason" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <div>
    <div><b>Data:</b></div>
    <div>{{this.tasks}}</div>
  </div>
   <div>
    <div><b>History:</b></div>
    <div v-for="item in history">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```